# Do all linearly independent set of vectors of E³ form a basis in E³?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vector-analysis

I have heard to check whether a set of vectors form a basis in E³, the easiest way is to find the determinant of the square matrix made by the components of the three vectors in E³. If the determinant value not equals to zero that means the set of vectors are linearly independent and evidently they form a basis in E³. Is it right? If right then do every linearly independent set of vectors in E³ form a basis in E³? Please help me to get it.

Comment: Please tell what $E^3$ is.

Comment: E³ means you can think R³

Comment: Ok. You should mention that in your post.

Comment: The empty set is linearly independent, but not a basis. A set with $n$ vectors in a vector space of dimension $n$ is a basis if and only if it is linearly independent if and only if it spans. The key here is presumably that your vector space is **three dimensional**, so a set of **three** vectors is a basis if and only if it is linearly independent. But there are plenty of linearly independent sets with *fewer* than three vectors.

Comment: Actually E³ means Euclidean space in 3 dimension. And I thought everyone know that. So sorry I should mention that.

Comment: "All linearly independent vectors of $E^3$" makes no sense. Linear independence is a property of a *set* of vectors, not of individual vectors. You can form a set of vectors that happens to be linearly independent (infinitely many such sets), but not a set of "linearly independent vectors", let alone "all" of them.